# Java uses a String constant with the quotes

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When i compare this constant string with MB inside with a variable with MB inside the result is false. The string constant looks like "MB" ([",M,B,"]=4 length) and my variable is "MB" ([M,B]=2 length). What's wrong here. Java cannot put the quotes inside the code into the string.

[image: string constant]

[image: Var 2]

```
public static final String gc_TelCodeFixed  = "FX";

if (!telcode.getId().equals(com.quoka.qis.db.constant.Constants.gc_TelCodeFixed)) 
    throw new TelcodeTypeMismatchException(telcode.getType());
```

Comment: can you put the comparison code?

Comment: Show some code, not a screen capture please.

Comment: It's "\"MB\"" in java

Comment: no. I always use equals. For String and for all other types of data.

Comment: putting a piece of code which does comparison, will help a lot

Comment: and can you show the Inspect content of telcode.getId() ?

Comment: i added the inspect of telcode.getId() as a second picture.

Comment: Did you try invalidating your IDE's caches, or reimporting the project, something like that? This does look very strange. Is it just in the IDE, or is code working in a way consistent with the string being 4 chars long?

Comment: the thing i don't understand is. why does java take the quotes inside the constant file into the string?

Comment: No. There is no integeers involved. getId() gives a string back. That string is 2 char long and ok. the problem is the string inside the constants. It's 4 chars long because the quotes are also inside the string. And i don't know where they come from.

Comment: @HasanTuncay Thanks for reply. Could you print unicode values of chars in constant string?

Comment: I suspect some stale .class file or cache in the IDE. I would do a clean rebuild of the code, and a reimport of the project.

Comment: I also suspect this to be some wierd IDE error. Never seen it before. It looks as if you are using Eclipse, right? I suggest tagging the question with this.

Comment: I found it. It was two things. I weird IDE error that shows the constants as 4 byte string with quotes and i was comparing integers with string. :-( This funny eclipse behaviour made me looking only for it instead of checking my code properly.

Answer (score 1):

Invisible characters might cause this behavior.

How did the "MB" got there? did you type them or copy-paste from another program?
Copy-paste operation might end up with invisible characters and text editors will not show them.

This can be easily reproduced by copying from PDF file with Linux Document Viewer.

Hope this helps,
Yaron